# It is possible to render a geometry as a blurry object?

Tags: modeling, rendering, cycles-render-engine, light

I was making an scene and thanks to the help of the people here, i managed to make a volumetric light..but now that i think the 'borders' are too sharp, and this light (seen on the picture) is nothing more than a deformed cube, so i need to know, it is possible to for example just select this single geometry and make it look blurry? actually what i need is to make the borders more blurry (like a light), but it could also help me in the future for references. (Oh, and I'm also using Cycles)

If anyone know how to do this, please let me know.

[image]

Comment: Try changing the density of the volume

Comment: Hmm, i already tried that, but if i do that, the texture/color (white) also goes a little transparent, i want to still keep the color/intensity. :/

Comment: Hmm . . . I'm not sure then

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15669/glow-with-depth-in-blender/15704#15704 and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15669/glow-with-depth-in-blender/15704#15704

Answer (score 3):

change the **object index** and use this node setup in the compositor

[image]

the **id mask** will create a mask from the object and  the **erode** will give it smooth edges

Comment: How can i change the object index? If i do that, it will not erase my previous node setup?

Comment: in OBJECT tab under RELATION there is PASS INDEX set it to 1

Comment: it won't effect your previous node setup

Comment: Compositing with dilate/erode (or blur) will affect the light circle on the ground too, needs testing IMHO.

Comment: When i go to pass index 2 if i edit the nodes, the nodes dissapear on the index 1...why?

Answer (score 2):

size up your mesh with volume shader. the light is supposed to be inside, but sharp borders are your meshe's borders.

[image]

Or change the blend factor of the spot shape.

[image: blend fac of spot light]