# Render and Preview are different

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light, world

I'm trying to create a simple scene like the scene depicted in the answer [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15669/glow-with-depth-in-blender):

[image]

I reproduced the Compositor and Volume scatter settings, and this is what I get when I render:

[image]

But in the Rendered viewport, the scene looks somewhat closer to what I'm trying to do:

[image]

I've tried branched path tracing and path tracing, I tried rendering without Compositing enabled, tweaked various settings, and read many questions on Blender SE about light rays but can't seem to understand why it won't work...

**Blend:**

[image]

Comment: It's working, you just need some strong gpu to render it. Here I colored the light, cranked it to 50k strength and rendered: http://i.stack.imgur.com/DtQv5.png

Comment: Bring up the light bounces for **volume** in the light paths section. Also try a lower value for **volume scatter**.

Comment: @Jerryno with what rendering settings? I get something completely different with 50k light. cegaton where is "light paths section"? Lower value in volume scatter's "density" or "anisotrop"? Is this how you produced the first image in the question?

Comment: @fabriced here's the file form the original post: [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=1102" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/1102/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is object named Plane.002 which is visible in rendering but not viewport. That's the culprit.

Hide it from render and you will get the same result in viewport and render.

Comment: O-M-G you're absolutely right! Noob mistake. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a blender expert but it seems as though you don't need the volume scatter or you don't have enough light in the scene.  Are the light sources on the same layer or a different one?  My question only matters if you might have turned on "This layer only" in the light settings.