# How to make Edge Glow?

Tags: animation, materials, workflow, effects

I am doing a zooming in and out animation for symbols.
And it suppose to have an *edge glow*, like in the example photo.

[image]

Is it possible to achieve without volumetric lighting because the lighting of the symbol should not be affected. I also get a grainy effect for some reason and I want the background to be completely black.

p.s. The symbol is floating in the air and has no objects around it, so emission on the sides wont be visible.

Comment: You can use a blur node in the compositor.

Comment: See if this helps: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/15680/1853

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is possibly easier to achieve in post production through the compositor.

You probably don't even need Cycles or "formal rendering" for somethning this simple. You can use the *OpenGL Render active viewport" or animation at the bottom of the 3D view.

Then add the glow effect and colors as desired in the compositor. You can use a *Filter > Blur* or a *Filter > Glow* node for this.

[image]