# How to Add Shininess on this Sun Object?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, blender-internal-render-engine

I need to Add Some Extra Highlight/Shine/Glossy to My Sun Object such that It feels like Sun is Emitting Sun-rays.

My Scene : 
[image]

It must feel like something like this :

[image]

Options I have tried :

1. Increasing Strength of Emission Parameter of Sun. (No Effect)
2. Mixing Glossy Shader with Emission Shader. (No Effect)

Comment: You can add a glare node in the compositor, or add volumetrics (volume scatter) to your scene

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make Edge Glow?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53309/how-to-make-edge-glow)

Answer (score 5):

You could use compositor and add Filter/Glare node.

[image: Quick sung glare example]

Comment: It's not working on my scene!