# how to create a flat glowing eyes in blender

Tags: modeling, texturing, modifiers

Can anyone please help me to create eyes for my model and i didn't  need a normal human eye,like i wanted  a type of wizard eyes.for ex-

[image: Desired effect]

And this is my model.

[image: model]

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53309/how-to-make-edge-glow/

Comment: This is a modeling question, not a compositor (glow) question, so the suggested duplicates aren't strictly relevant.

Answer (score 1):

You can just add a "Emission" Node and turn the color to pink and then apply the material to the eyes.
[image]

Then apply the material to the eyes.[image]

Add another material to the rest of the mesh and behold! Your wizzard/witch looks cool!
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much gal in .I really appreciate u for spending your valuable time to answer.But i asked how to create flat eyes.

Answer (score 1):

As Gavin states, but for the glow you'll also need to add an Emission pass to the render layer, and in the compositor, run the emission pass to a blur filter node (or a glare node - there are several possibilities).
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much sir for spending your valuable time for answering but I wanted how to make a flat eye for my model

Comment: Do you want the eye to move independently of the main body? Or is it like a decal on a Lego model (something like what I've done above), and doesn't move, ever?