# how to make glowing 2d eyes

Tags: modeling, texturing, modifiers, uv-image-editor

i need help with making the 2d model into 2d eyes i need to know how to make 2d eyes, that are rounded slightly, I want them to be black with glowing white eyes, I want them to be looking like a glass screen.
[image]

be sure to answer or tell me if its is even possible what im asking. thank you,
[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Have you looked for other question regarding this topic on this site?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=glow+eyes

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53309/how-to-make-edge-glow

Comment: @susa i have tried uv editor to make the white pupils but i couldnt make them glow so i scrapped it also it wasn't shiny loke a screen/ glass

Comment: @Carlo ive searched on the site butt to no success, ive tried YouTube as well but they don't have what im looking for

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more information on what you've tried that isn't working, that way we don't waste our time suggesting things you've tried already or by guessing what you want to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get glowing eyes by using a Spherical Gradient shaped further with a ColorRamp, and run through and Emission Shader. To get the "Pupils" in the right place, you will have to use individual Mapping Nodes for each, and position them manually (based on the shape/position of your mesh(s)). Since it's just black and white, you can get away with plugging the emission straight into the material output, but you said you wanted a "glass screen" (I take as shiny) surface, so in my example, I mixed it with the Principled BSDF with the Roughness set to 0. Don't forget to turn on Bloom.

[image: GlowEyes]

Comment: i really appreciate this, thank you, i would like to ask if every step i have to do is on the image you sent?? also how do i get the lighten node?

Comment: You said you already made the eyes, so yeah, It should be. Like I said, the values in the Mapping Nodes may be different for you than me, and the ColorRamp sliders might need slightly different positions, but basically that's it.

Comment: i got the black skinniness however the brightness isnt there along with the white pupils, have i done anything wrong?

Comment: Did you increase the emission strength and/or turn on bloom in the render properties panel?

Comment: its the exact same as the image

Comment: Not syre then, it should be bright. Oh, I just saw you asked about the "Lighten" Node - it's actually a MixRBG node set to "lighten" ("add" works too as I'm just adding the two different pupils into one texture)

Comment: yeah i managed to get the node but the rest isn't working even though it looks accurate to what you showed me, is there a way for me to show you the image of what i  have done

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118433/discussion-between-justimpact-and-christopher-bennett).

Comment: My object is Y axis aligned, which is why I translated by 1.5 on the Y in the Mapping node. Your object is X axis aligned, so you should be altering the X axis of your mapping node. But remember, because our meshes aren't the same shape/size/orientation, etc... you can't expect the same values in the Mapping node to behave the same for your project as they do for mine (mine is 1.5, yours could be 2.5 or more (or less)). Play around with your X location values on the Mapping Node to see if you can make the "dot" appear.

Comment: yeah its not appearing anywhere, is there a setting that im missing

Comment: good news mate everything is working fine when it come to nodes, i just need to fix the mesh itself, thx mate im honestly grateful for the help

Comment: ok so yours is curved just like my image, however mine is curved nd its not showing the pupil, ive used a flat pane and it works fine, but as soon as i curve the plane is gets small and or it gets lost

Comment: Let's put it this way - the "sphere" that makes up your eye dot is out there, floating in 3D space. You have to use the mapping node to bring it to a place where it intersects your plane - that is where you see the dot. Object texture coordinates puts 0,0,0 at the object's origin, so it shouldn't be far away. Just "search the axes" for the magic spot.