# Cycles: Need help combining a glowing transparent texture with the rest of the material

Tags: node-editor

So I use Cycles and am trying to make Godzilla with his spines glowing. I have already created the material for his whole body (which is one node set-up), now what I need to do is create another separate node set-up for his spines to glow. I have a PNG alpha image texture of the glowing spines, but I don't know how to properly add this texture (transparency) and have it glow at the same time.

Also, once I finish the spine set-up, I was wondering how I would combine that node set up with the rest of the body? Sorry if the question is very vague and/or has a simple answer! In the future I'm gonna be adding alpha textures to an object, and so I need to know how to:

1) Make that texture glow while being able to key frame it (so it goes from not glowing to glowing and back).

2) Be able to combine it with the rest of the material/object.

I included a screenshot. To be honest I don't think I even added the glow texture right because it doesn't look how it should. Even though it was rendered in Internal, this video I made shows how it use to look and how I wish it did:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oZIfAVE_ga4 (Sorry, it was my first time using the shutter option with motion blur so naturally I cranked that up and it's a really blurry vid)
[image]

Comment: Sorry, I really tried making sense of your question. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: In case the problem is the glow effect: Objects with emission shaders do not glow, they emit light. So if you want this glow effect (emphasis on effect) you would have to go through the compositor, that processes the image after rendering. There, the motion blur, light glow, lens flares, etc. can be added and also keyframed as far as I know. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15669/glow-with-depth-in-blender

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I had 2 questions: One was how would I achieve the same glow effect I did with the model in Internal (left a link to the video, in Internal I just added the alpha texture and had it emit light as I added the compositing glare filter to achieve said glow. I don't know how to get similar results here in Cycles), and two was how do I combine the spine glow to the main model's material which is it's skin. How do I put together the spine glow set up with the body set up.

Comment: You can assign the glowing/emitting spines material to the specific spine vertices. then you can animate the materials separately.

Comment: Sorry bro I'm not that good, do you think you can go into further detail?