# Why the texture is not glowing

Tags: texturing, materials, light

I have created a tail light. With the material and texture i have setup.

[image]

[image]

What is missing in the nodes. Im not getting glow from the emission nodes. I have increase the strength of the emission but cant see  the texture from it.

[image]

How can i get a bike head light glow and emission from the above nodes. Any suggestion or help. Thanks

**More emission**
[image]

Comment: what do you mean by glowing? It is emitting a light, there's no glow because you can only do it with the Compositor (or with some tricks in materials)... not sure what you mean...

Comment: @moonboots i think im confuse to ask a question. Will if the headlight is in air how can i give a base and make it glow. Below miceterminator given answer he has added a plane but my headlights are in air how can i show emission from it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Glow with depth in Blender?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15669/glow-with-depth-in-blender)

Comment: You need to turn on *Bloom* in *Render Properties*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all the emission is obviously working:

[[image: added plane]] 
[image: no light]

so the question would be in my opinion on how to make it more obvious that there is an emission going on.

Here I suggest two routes:

First, adding additional geometry, that the light can actually illuminate(scatter or reflect upon). So once this is put in a scene the problem will solve it self.

If the object needs to be standalone, you can add a plane for it to rest on and add lens effects that make the illumination bounce in the camera.

Also tweaking the filmic color management might give you the desired effect.

Here is my short effort:

[image: effort]

see [here](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.steg-electronics.ch%2Fgfx1664621%2Fvbfgf.PNG&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.steg-electronics.ch%2Fde%2Farticle%2FMagicshine-Seemee-20-Bike-Tail-Light-24704659.aspx&docid=ZIHcjrPstIS-ZM&tbnid=sN0oOs8YLRB77M%3A&vet=10ahUKEwii8ouisefdAhV_wAIHHY25A8AQMwhXKBQwFA..i&w=835&h=841&itg=1&client=ubuntu&bih=1962&biw=1318&q=bike%20taillight&ved=0ahUKEwii8ouisefdAhV_wAIHHY25A8AQMwhXKBQwFA&iact=mrc&uact=8) and [here](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fae01.alicdn.com%2Fkf%2FHTB1u7RyJFXXXXX3aXXXq6xXFXXXN%2FBike-Cycling-Lights-Waterproof-5-LED-2-Lasers-3-Modes-Bike-Taillight-Safety-Warning-Light-Bicycle.jpg_640x640.jpg&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.aliexpress.com%2Fitem%2FCycling-Bike-Rear-Tail-Safety-LED-Warning-Light-5-LED-2-Laser-Light-red-line-EA14%2F32599570661.html&docid=-2QlvK850eWhBM&tbnid=bGtxiOGqz6Qy7M%3A&vet=10ahUKEwii8ouisefdAhV_wAIHHY25A8AQMwg6KAEwAQ..i&w=640&h=640&client=ubuntu&bih=1962&biw=1318&q=bike%20taillight&ved=0ahUKEwii8ouisefdAhV_wAIHHY25A8AQMwg6KAEwAQ&iact=mrc&uact=8) for reference

[This part](https://youtu.be/06A_l95vJWw?t=4424) might also be interesting

Comment: sorry i have to edit the question. I want to say it that the head light is in air so how can add a plane below it. I want to show its emitting light but as its in air how can i give a support below.

Comment: I tried with the above nodes. The headlights not glowing rest the steel material glows https://imgur.com/gallery/EISKwXn

Comment: Probably your emission node is not strong enough or your backlight is too strong. I bumped the strength to 40 end decreased backlight strength to 1/3?

Comment: I increase the emission from 10 to 25 and the result above in the question image added. I want to glow the head and tail light why im getting glow to the steel parts and the glow is too add.

Comment: Thanks for the nodes i delete all the nodes except fog glow and threshold .100. Got the cool result.

Answer (score 3):

You could do it with the *Glare* effect of the *Compositor*, but here is a quick trick to do it:

- Create your object and give it an *Emission* shader.
- Create a second bigger object that will contain your first object.
- Give this second object the following material: a mix between an *Emission* shader and a *Transparent* shader, with an *Input* > *Layer Weight* shader as the factor.
- Play with the *Blend* factor of the *Layer Weight* until you have what you want.

Explanation: the Layer Weight shader works a little bit like a Fresnel, it allows you to determine what happens on the perimeter of the shape as it is viewed, here it allows you to give transparency to the perimeter.

[image]

Comment: hehe.... the  old-school way! :D

Comment: ah ah that's the best way