# How to make image transparency of clouds brighter

Tags: node-editor, image, transparency

I am trying to make a pillar cloud using an image transparency. I have a basic node set up for making the image show with transparent background. But I would like to make the cloud pillar glow. I am not sure how to set up the nodes to make this happen. I am using Blender 2.79   [image]

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information on how you set up your project. [Add images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) that might help us understand what you have done so far.  See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)

Comment: Thanks I edited the post and added a picture.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you are using an image to determine transparency, you can change the brightness by using any of the following nodes: gamma, color ramp, Bright Cont or even a Converter>Math node to affect the values.

[image]

To make things glow there are already [endless posts on the subject](https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=glow) in this site.

Start with this one:

[Glow with depth in Blender?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15669/glow-with-depth-in-blender/15704#15704)

Comment: I tried the different nodes you suggested in the Alpha but it seems the transparency no longer works. I used a half of a cylinder to put this cloud object on and it starts showing when I put a new node where you suggested. In some cases it goes solid. I am sure I am doing something wrong. Thanks for the link for glowing objects.