# How could a lightsabers bright core be maintained when motion blurred?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, compositing-nodes

Without motion blur it looks like this:

[image]

With motion blur and shutter 1.0

The core dissolves:

[image]

The compositing is similar to [Post-processing Lightsabers in Blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3636/post-processing-lightsabers-in-blender)

Comment: Maybe you can use a trick: The particle info node has properties for velocity and angular velocity. Maybe you can render the blade of the light saber as a single particle attatched to the handle and use the velocity to scale the brightness.

Comment: @maddin45 thanks for you suggestion, I indeed tried already to use a single hair particle, also a disc-segment with controlled by a shape key but couldn't find out how to drive shape key. Particle info node seems promising, but a bit much research for (this ;-) afternoon.

Comment: The id mask with motion blur is rather pixelated in cycles. What about blur/dilate the mask then fill in more colour to solidify the centre a bit more?

Comment: @sambler Thanks, I will try it I will take a while since I'm new to compositing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your core is not bright enough, give the core emission strength between 500 and 1000 and then it should be bright with shutter at 1.0. Do the soft red glow in postpro also.